# Counter clockwise steps for stepper motor on emu8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I know that stepper motor can do clockwise steps using the below commands, but how can I do the counter-clockwise steps?

```
MOV AL, 001b ; initialize.
OUT 7, AL

MOV AL, 011b ; half step 1.
OUT 7, AL

MOV AL, 010b ; half step 2.
OUT 7, AL

MOV AL, 110b ; half step 3.
OUT 7, AL
```

I copied this code Twice,it resulted a 90 degree clock wise rotation
Now i need it to do a 90 degree counter clock wise rotation,but when i put the codes in reverse the result is not what i want

Comment: isn't there a 101b missing?

Comment: my guess : run the sequence of commands in reverse order

Comment: this could be helpful: http://www.imagesco.com/articles/picstepper/01.html

Comment: @Tommylee2k No I've copied this code from emu8086 help

Comment: @planetmaker I did what you said,the result was a 45 degree counter clock wise rotation,what i want is a 90 degree counter clock wise so pasted it once again but the result wasn't another 45 degree rotation

Comment: I don't know the documentation, but my assumption is that the bits drive which brush of the motor will be powered: 001 - 011 - 010 - 110 - 100 - 101 - 001... and you can walk left to right or right to left through this sequence to get a smooth rotation; but I'd expect 60° rotation for each step in that case ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clock wise rotation:

```
MOV AL, 06h

OUT 7, AL

MOV AL, 04h

OUT 7, AL

MOV AL, 03h 

OUT 7, AL

MOV AL, 02h

OUT 7, AL
```

counter clock wise rotation:

```
MOV AL, 03h 

OUT 7, AL

MOV AL, 01h

OUT 7, AL

MOV AL, 06h 

OUT 7, AL

MOV AL, 02h

OUT 7, AL
```

Comment: 3->1->6->2 can't be right, one stepper motors you only change the state of ONE magnet, ... 1 --> 6 would be 001 to 110 ... this won't be a smooth turn, or wont work at all. This is why "normal" stepper motors usually have 4 steps for one round. not 3 as written by the OP, there's obviously something ("halfstep 4") missing, if "001" is "initialize"